# getURL (from RCurl package) doesn't work in a loop

Tags: r, rcurl

I have a list of URL named URLlist and I loop over it to get the source code for each of those URL :

```
for (k in 1:length(URLlist)){
    temp = getURL(URLlist[k])
}
```

Problem is for some random URL, the code get stuck and I get the error message:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
    transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

But when I try the getURL function, not in the loop, with the URL which had a problem, it perfectly works.

Any help please ? thank you very much

Comment: It works without problem on my system. What kind of URL are you trying to download ?

Comment: Works fine on my machine as well. What does `URLlist` look like?

Comment: with how many url did you try ? I am retrieving URL from yahoo finance so I don't think that the problem if from the server. My URLlist is really basic "http://www.url1.com" "http://www.url2.com" ...

Comment: How many URL do *you* download ? And I really think it would help to have a precise example of the URLs used.

Comment: there are all URL like this : http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT&d=4&e=2&f=2013&g=d&a=2&b=13&c=1986&ignore=.csv I want to download about a hundread of them but it randomly get stuck, somethimes before the 10 first one and sometime almost at the end of the list

Comment: If they are all URLs like the one you just gave, why are you trying to use `getURL`? If you just want to download a bunch of CSV files, you can use `read.csv`.

Comment: OP, I'd argue you should accept the answer if it worked for you...

Answer (score 3):

Hard to tell for sure without more information, but it could just be the requests getting sent too quickly, in which case just pausing between requests could help :

```
for (k in 1:length (URLlist)) {
    temp = getURL (URLlist[k])
    Sys.sleep (0.2) 
}
```

I'm assuming that your actual code does something with 'temp' before writing over it in every iteration of the loop, and whatever it does is very fast.

You could also try building in some error handling so that one problem doesn't kill the whole thing. Here's a crude example that tries twice on each URL before giving up:

```
for (url in URLlist) {
    temp = try (getURL (url))
    if (class (temp) == "try-error") {
        temp = try (getURL (url))
        if (class (temp) == "try-error")
            temp = paste ("error accessing", url)
        }    
    Sys.sleep(0.2) 
}
```

Comment: As you don't use `k` except to index `URLlist`, I suggest: `for (url in URLlist) { }`

Comment: Done! Although an indexing variable might be nice to actually do anything useful with the downloaded data...

Comment: If you're going to populate a list with the results, `lapply` would be appropriate.

Comment: I'm with you. I was trying to avoid fiddling too much with the implementation of the loop for the sake of staying focused on the original question about getting the downloads to work. Especially since though it seems awful likely OP is populating a list, it's not 100% clear.

Comment: I had this same (seemingly rare) problem, and the error handling worked for me (but not the sleeping on its own). Any advice on how to automate the max number of tries before giving up? Beyond 2 tries the nesting starts to get messy...